# Passing Constants in method Spring Web Flow with ZK

Tags: zk, spring-webflow-2

I`m working with **springwebflow 2** and **Zk 6**.

I`m calling a method with 2 constants parameters

```
   <on-render>
      <evaluate expression="service.mythod(mypackage.Constants.ID_CATALOG_PERSON_SUFFIX_TYPE, mypackage.Constants.ApplicationConstant.LANGUAGE_ISO)" 
                result="viewScope.listSuffix" />
        </on-render>
```

It invoke the method but the parameter are null :

Constant CLASS:

```
   public class Constants {

    public final static String ID_CATALOG_PARTY_TYPE = "PARTY_TYPE";
    public final static String ID_CATALOG_PERSON ="PERSON";
}
```

can anybody help me?

Comment: Ummm... I'm assuming you pasted an incomplete `Constants` class? The ones you're referencing in your Web Flow are not the ones you're showing in the class.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Expression Templating](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#d0e12128) something like this:

```
<evaluate expression="service.method(#{T(mypackage.Constants).ID_CATALOG_PERSON_SUFFIX_TYPE}, ...)"/>
```